Can I create an eslint comment that is interpreted as an error?
We have branch protection and pre-push hooks in our system that force us to have no eslint errors or warnings in order to push to main/master.
Sometimes, while debugging something, I will modify a parameter in the code to make debugging easier.  For instance, a timeout in a network resource would normally trigger while I'm debugging, so I either disable it or make the timeout very large.
The problem is I know one of these days I'm going to forget I did that and my temporary change will make its way into the code despite everyone's well-intentioned code reviews.
I'm thinking it would be great if I could add a comment at the line where I spiked the setting that would force an eslint error and prevent me from pushing my branch.
Something like:
// eslint-force-error DON'T LET ME CHECK THIS IN!!!!
network.timeout = 1000000; // 1000;

Before I can push, I would have to pay attention to this, and that's when I revert these two lines and rest easy that I didn't break something that shows up much later.
I don't think eslint has something precisely like this, but is there some meta-behavior with some other comment I can take advantage of?

That's what unit and integration tests are for. If you mess with the settings, it's not ESLint's job to catch that, but your unit/integration test should go "yeah this thing that's supposed to take 1 second is suddenly timing out, fix your code".

// FIMXEthen https://gist.github.com/kuy/5d1151fd5897a9b84c06 or https://bia.is/git-pre-commit-hook-avoid-committing-fixmes/

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In a perfect world, yes, but sometimes you're a startup that can't afford to not have any technical debt, so having this tool in my pocket let's me get what needs to get done right now faster.  Thanks to Mureinik for answering the question.

You can use the no-warning-comments rule, and configure it to a list of prefixes you want to disallow in your comments. E.g.:
 "rules": {
    "no-warning-comments": ["error", {"terms": ["FIXME", "NOPE"]}]
 }

